# Error in gradle caches while trying to install the app android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ide

```
Trailing char < > at index 99: C:\Users\xxxx\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\76f321d0ac90a16888f2ef8d01de6439\jetified-main
```

The gradle build tools version is 3.6.3

I'm trying to install the app on a device and whenever I click on "run", the error it shows is this. I've tried clearing the caches and cleaning the project. It didn't work. Can someone answer it? It's a big blocker for me

Comment: delete you build folder and try it,

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work. I research a bit and found that a file in my libs folder was being created with a space due to a mis type build.gradle. Thanks for the comment @RaviGadipudi